# How to print each element of a list on a new line in a nested list

Tags: python, list, nested-loops, nested-lists

I wanted to print each individual element of a list that's in nested list. it should also print symbols to show where the different lists end. There are only going to be 3 lists total in the big list.

For Example,

```
list1 = [['assign1', 'assign2'], ['final,'assign4'], ['exam','study']]
```

Output should be:

```
######################
assign1
assign2
######################
----------------------
final
assign4
----------------------
*************************
exam
study
*************************
```

I know that to print an element in a normal list it is:
for element in list1:
print element

I am unaware of what steps to take next.

Comment: Is there a single nesting level ? In other words can nested list contains nested lists ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another `for` loop around the one you know how to create. So:

```
for list2 in list1:
  # print some stuff here
  for word in list2:
    print(word)
  # print some more stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is a single nesting level.

```py
symbols = "#-*"
list1 = [['assign1', 'assign2'], ['final', 'assign4'], ['exam','study']]
for i, element in enumerate(list1):
    symbol = symbols[i%len(symbols)]
    print(symbol*20)
    print('\n'.join(element))
    print(symbol*20)
```

Comment: You should use `print('\n'.join(element))` on line #6 as that would print more like the requested format instead of printing the nested list on a single line.